# Increase the performace of the code by reducing the number of ssh

Tags: unix, scripting, shell, ssh

This function take hugh amount of time to calculate the status of a process, beacuse every time it has to ssh into the machine and find the status of a process.

I only have four machines and around 50+ process to monitor and the details are mentioned into configDaemonDetails.txt

like:

```
abc@sn123|Daemon_1|processname_1
abc@sn123|Daemon_2|processname_2
efg@sn321|Daemon_3|processname_3
```

**How to reduce the time with doing ssh once into a machine and finding all its process informations as defined in the txt file. ?**

```
CheckProcessStatus ()
{
         echo "              ***** Checking Process Status ***** "
         echo "========================================================="
         IFS='|'
         cat configDaemonDetails.txt | grep -v "^#" | while read MachineDetail Daemon ProcessName
         do

                Status=`ssh -f -T ${MachineDetail} ps -ef | egrep -v "grep|less|vi|more" | grep "$ProcessName"`
                RunTime=`echo "$Status" | sed -e 1'p' -e '1,$d' | awk '{print $5" "$6}'`
                if [ -z "$Status" ]
                        then
                                echo "The Process is DOWN $Daemon | $ProcessName "
                        else
                                echo "The Process $Daemon | $ProcessName is up since  $RunTime"
                fi

         done

         echo "-----------------------------------------------------"

}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just fetch the entire `ps -ef` output at once, and then parse it appropriately?  I suspect that is what you are asking, and maybe all you want is an example of how to do that?  If that is the case, say so and I'll flesh out an example.

Comment: how do I provide all process name from the file to ps -ef ?

Comment: Don't provide them all at once.  Get the ENTIRE output from ps -ef on the remote machine, and process it all at your local machine.  Or if that is too much, you can do a ps -uf {username} if all the procs are running under the same account.

Comment: can u suggest how can i reduce the time for getting memory and cpu utilization 
I am doing similarly(ssh one by one and fetching the memory & CPU utilised for a process).

CPU_Status=`ssh -f -T ${MachineDetail} ps -eo pcpu -o user -o args | egrep -v "grep|less|vi|more" | grep "$PrcessName" | awk '$1>5.0'`

Answer (score 0):

`SSH` is a bit over kill for getting status of a process, I'd suggest using `SNMP` instead.

e.g, you can get a process list like this:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cPASSWORD HOST 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1
```

Take a look at [this](http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_process.html) Nagios plugin that does process checks, and look in the [code](http://nagios.manubulon.com/check_snmp_process.pl) for the actual SNMP OIDs.